# Does the Violence Interrupters program reduce shootings and homicides in Washington, D.C.?

Tags: united-states, law-enforcement

[Violence Interrupters](https://www.violenceinterrupters.org/about-us) is a program to reduce gang-related retaliations.

They have [a presence in Washington D.C.](https://www.wusa9.com/article/news/local/dc/hes-been-shot-at-hes-lost-friends-inside-the-life-of-one-of-dcs-most-violent-neighborhoods/65-c1075db8-8f3a-445d-a822-5b94f7a548d1).

I found [a local news article](https://wjla.com/news/local/community-members-notice-decrease-in-shootings-in-benning-terrace-neighborhood) that claims:

> Community members in the Benning Terrace neighborhood have noticed a decrease in shootings since January.

and

> According to the city’s latest crime statistics, there have been zero homicides in the Benning Terrace neighborhood since the group began their work.

I found an [2012 evaluation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266285578_Evaluation_of_Baltimore's_Safe_Streets_Program_Effects_on_Attitudes_Participants'_Experiences_and_Gun_Violence) about a similar program in Baltimore, but I'm interested in a credible report across the entire city of DC.

Have Violence Interrupters been successful in reducing shootings and homicides in Washington D.C.?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I'm concerned there is no notable claim. There is a small, fairly new group with lofty goals, but are they claiming to have met them yet? If no-one believes that there is anything more than the beginning of anecdotal evidence to support their work, what is the doubtful claim we are addressing?